# Android Studio run command when back button is clicked in Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This back button are added automatically on `ActionBar`

[image]

I want button to run the command below instead.

```
if (mWebView.canGoBack()) 
{
    mWebView.goBack();    
}
else
{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The button is automatically added I didn't use any command I don't know where to place my command can anyone help me?

Comment: Please check your manifest file, there you can see a parent activity for this Activity, remove that.

Comment: I removed the parent activity button is now gone how do I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // todo: goto back activity from here

                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) 
                {
                    mWebView.goBack();    
                }
                else
                {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (mWebView.canGoBack()) 
            {
                mWebView.goBack();    
            }
            else
            {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    });
```